# Split Fortran character string of unknown length but known substring format by commas?

Tags: string, fortran

I'm trying to split an input variable to some Fortran code by commas. The variable is a character string that contains a variable number of dates, but the dates are always in DD-MMM-YYYY format.

An example of such a string:

```
04-DEC-2015,10-DEC-2015,23-DEC-2015,25-DEC-2015
```

It's not always four dates, but it is always an 11-character date in that format.

I simply want to print these dates on separate lines; the current code:

```
write(outfile,10) '     - ', TRIM(days)
```

Prints:

```
     -  04-DEC-2015,10-DEC-2015,23-DEC-2015,25-DEC-2015
```

And I want to write something that prints:

```
     -  '04-DEC-2015'
     -  '10-DEC-2015'
     -  '23-DEC-2015'
     -  '25-DEC-2015'
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this (I'm pretty new to Fortran)? I'm thinking counting the number of commas in the string, adding 1 to get the number of dates, and inside a loop creating a `CHARACTER(11)` variable that fits each date, getting 11 characters from the string at a time (skipping commas), and printing that date in the format I want. Is that too convoluted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has previously been suggested, a list-directed read from an internal file will handle the splitting on commas without more effort.  For

```
character(11) :: split_days(MAX_DAYS)=''
ndays = ...
read(days,*) split_days(1:ndays)
```

to work we need to know the value of `ndays`.  If you're happy with something like

```
ndays = (len_trim(days)+1)/12
ndays = INDEX(days,',',BACK=.TRUE)/12+1
```

or

```
ndays = COUNT([(days(i:i),i=1,LEN_DAYS)].eq.',')+1
```

then everything is good.

Alternatively, you could have an allocatable array

```
character(11), allocatable :: split_days(:)
ndays = ...
allocate (split_days(ndays))
read(days,*) split_days
```

Alternatively, you don't need to read the internal file (list-directed or otherwise), although I probably would if I trusted the form of my input data.

```
do i=1,MAX_DAYS
  split_days(i)=days(12*(i-1)+1:)
  if (INDEX(days(12*i:),',').eq.0) exit
end do
```

A further possibility with the list-directed read approach is to choose a large number to read, and if that fails, try again reading fewer.  This makes sense only in more tricky situations.

Finally, you can use the usual array shrinking/growing tricks if desired.

---

If you're just after printing, not storing, then the loop approach above avoids messing about with an array of unknown length:

```
do i=1,MAX_DAYS
  print '("     - ''",A11,"''")', days(12*(i-1)+1:)
  if (INDEX(days(12*i:),',').eq.0) exit
end do
```

Comment: `read(days,*) split_days(1:ndays)` <- this solves the "severe (24): end-of-file during read" error I had when reading a too-small dates list into what was originally a destination that was too long. (Originally of the form `read(days,*) split_days`). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use an internal read.

```
 character(len=47) :: in = '04-DEC-2015,10-DEC-2015,23-DEC-2015,25-DEC-2015'
 character(len=11) :: out(4)
 read(in,*)out
```

note this is splitting on the commas. If the strings between the commas are more or less than 11 characters they will be truncated or blank padded.  Also note there can not be spaces in the strings or read will split there too.

you do need to know how many to read. If you know they are all length 11 you could do `(len(in)+1)/12` , or use `index` to count the commas.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but notice the number of dates is variable. The OP will have to count something anyway. When I tried to iplement this completely it ended up more convoluted than the original proposed OP's solution.

Comment: I meant counting how many array elements are filled, but if you allocate it to the right length, it will work in the end (to avoid blank lines).

Comment: This is great, and works if I know the number of days. Like you said, if I set     character(len=11) :: out(4) it works, but I need that 4 to be a variable, say p, and if I try to set     character(len=11) :: out(p) after calculating     p = (len(in)+q)/12, it gives me an "A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section." error when compiling.

Any idea how I can set the size of out *after* calculating the number of missing dates?

Comment: @vladimir-f Can I set character(11) :: out(31) in the specification section of the code and later reduce the size of out? I won't have more than 31 dates, and if I can cut out's size down to 4 (or whatever the calculated value of p is) from 31 in the executable section, read(in,*)out works. Otherwise if out stays at size 31, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Addition to the above: If I set out to be too large (say character(11) :: out(31) ), then the read statement ( read(in,*)out ) exits with an error "severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read"; looks like that's because in is too short to fill out if out's length is 31. The problem remains: how do I have out's length automatically set to (len(in)+1)/12?

Comment: These are the complications I mentioned. It is not that simple as it looks in the answer. Either use a subarray, or allocate it to the exact length.

Comment: To be more explicit, I think you can declare `out` as `character(11) :: out(31)`, get the number of items as `p = (len_trim(in)+1)/12` (assuming there is no space), and `read(in,*) out( 1 : p )` (i.e., read into a subarray). Alternatively, we can declare "out" as `character(11), allocatable :: out(:)`, allocate it as `allocate( out( p ) )`, and then `read(in,*) out` (here no index necessary because `out` is of right size). But the latter approach may need reallocation of `out` (when `in` has different number of items), so the first approach might be more convenient.